# ParseSwift: how to declare a [String: Any]? property for a ParseObject?

Tags: parsing, parse-platform, parse-ios-sdk

I am trying to use `Parse-Swift` SDK, and specifically in the app database I have some properties which are dictionaries, like this one:

```
elements: Dictionary<String, Any>

["test_string": "hello", "test_number": 22.2] // an example of a value for this property
```

Now I tried to write this `ParseObject` in Swift:

import Foundation; import ParseSwift

```
struct TestObject: ParseObject {
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?
    var originalData: Data?

    var elements: [String: Any]?
}
```

But doing this, I get these errors:

> Type 'TestObject' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
>
> Type 'TestObject' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
>
> Type 'TestObject' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
>
> Type 'TestObject' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

What should I do? Thank you for your help

Comment: I guess the problem can be the Any. Can you please try with `[String: String]?` to see what happens?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo btw the code compiles, but I get an error then because it cannot read the double values: `Error decoding parse-server response`

Comment: I'm not a Swift expert and I'm not sure it makes sense, but what If you try with `[String: Hashable]?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` isn’t `Codable` meaning it doesn't conform to the `Codable` protocol and can't be sent to a Parse Server using JSON which is why the compiler is complaining.

If you want something similar to `Any`, you can add the [AnyCodable](https://github.com/Flight-School/AnyCodable) package via SPM to your project and use the following types: `AnyCodable`, `AnyEncodable`, `AnyDecodable`. See the notes in the [documentation](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-Swift/release/documentation/parseswift/query/findexplain(usingmongodb:options:)-58al/) and more info [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/pull/127#issue-866870311) and [here](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/issues/141#issue-890290238). So your object will look like:

```swift
struct TestObject: ParseObject {
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?
    var originalData: Data?

    var elements: [String: AnyCodable]?
}
```

To access the value of `AnyCodable`, `AnyEncodable`, `AnyDecodable`; you use the `.value` property and attempt to cast it to the expected type. You can check the [ParseSwift test cases for examples](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/search?q=AnyCodable). Using your `TestObject` type:

```swift
var object = TestObject()
object.elements["myKey"] = AnyCodable("My value")
guard let storedValue = object.elements["myKey"]?.value as? String else {
   print("Should have casted to String")
   return
}
print(storedValue) // Should print "My value" to console
```