# Parse-Swift: unable to find the appropriate type to save data in an Object type field of a Parse Object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Using Parse-Swift 4.7.0 on MacOS, Xcode 14.0ß7

One of my table is made of Parse Objects containing a field of type `Object` (as it appears in Sashido/Parse Server). This field contains a dictionary of type [String: Any] representing a JSON dictionary.

With the Parse Objc SDK this dictionary was saved successfully as is with the PFObject.

With the Parse-Swift framework, I tried:

- To define the variable type as ParseBytes, containing the json object as Data. Saving failed blaming to get an Object iso ParseBytes.
- To define the variable type as Data, without success
- To define the variable type as a [String: Any] dictionary. But as Any is not Equatable, the merge(:) func doesn't accept it.

What's the way to save this [String: Any] dictionary in the Object field?

Comment: This question is a duplicate and was previously answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71851227

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved by creating an Equatable Struct!